# Iframe style being overrridden by website's css

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

1. I work for an adtech. We show ads using iframe but for one particular website where we are showing ads my iframe height is being overriden.
2. The style that overrides my css style is as follows:-

```css
#story-sec .led-content .cont-bot .right-side .news-detail-landing iframe:not(.instagram-media) {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 200px!important;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

3. I create iframe dynamically using javascript. The site is overriding my css.

---

```
var iframe = createHtmlElement("iframe");          
setAttributesForElement(iframe, { 'vspace':'0', 'hspace':'0', 'scrolling':'no', 'id':'myIframeId', 'frameborder':'0', 'marginwidth': '0', 'marginheight': '0', 'allowtransparency':'true', } );            
setStyle(iframe, {'margin':'0px', 'width':'100%', 'height':'100%', 'padding':'0px'} );
```

---

So in above code setAttributes and setStyle are function that I have which take input and set style adn attributes for html elements.

4. Is there a way to avoid my css being overridden ? I tried searching for answers but got not much clarity.
5. I can set class named instagram-media for my iframe which solves the issue but the ads are placed on different sites so I might encounter same problem again. so looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: I think on the problamatic website, they are overriding your iframe.

Comment: yes. but how to avoid it or skip that override ?

Comment: why don't you just add `style rule` directly, e.g. `<iframe style='...`, with `!important` postfix? It overrides stylesheets defined rules. Also, id rules definition always overrides class style rules, with same 'weight'(`!important`/not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had experience of work like that, so in those cases I would usually do this:
- Target the iframe you created with > css pointer.
- Is there any possibility to set !important flags on your styles?
- Try to create a very long distinctive class name for your iframe.

Comment: Nice catch. And congratulations for your paralax @ github. How do I would say... spaciba?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned adding a class resolves the issue but that you're worried about, another website using that same class and again over writing your css.

Your best bet may be to simply use some really obscure class?

Like...

class="YourCompany_iframeCSS_InsertADateHere_AnAlphaNumericStringHere"

Comment: :-  Adding a class means there is one class excluded above in css mentioned like this iframe: not (instagram-media). If I set that className to my iframe then issue is resolved . !important is overriding iframe height and width. So it might occur again on some site. So looking for a solution.